# Vuex Vue How to print child component without render it on parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a button on a summary page that `@click` will print a completed from that is not being rendered on that specific instance.

what is the best practice to print a component without having to render it on the active page?

I tried rendering the component on the page with `visibility: hidden;` so that the component renders then I can click the button to `window.print()`but this seems like a hack and not the best practice plus it adds a huge empty space to my instance.

I need a way to print the form (component) without actually rendering it on the page.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I implemented a routine to do this by creating a hidden iframe and injecting the HTML and CSS of the element I want to print into it, then I print the iframe. Maybe try something like that?

Comment: if the problem with rendering the component in the page is the empty space you can try `display: none;` (or `v-show="false"`) instead of `visibility: hidden;`. You can also use a media query to show it only when printing the page or print just that form (`@media print` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples) features (`@media print` in your case). Just create a CSS class that will always apply `display: none;`, except when a browser in print mode.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', { template: '<h1 class="print">Hello World</h1>' }, )

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.print {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .print {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```